# How to remove background, border and not-allowed-pointer from disabled input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap: How can I remove the background, border and the not-allowed-pointer in form fields when in disabled state? Without altering the same on other forms disabled fields...

I tried this, without any success (using AngularJS):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-disabled="toggle" ng-class="{'no-extras': toggle}" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
```

And CSS:

```
.no-extras {
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: default;
}
```

See code here http://plnkr.co/edit/1AuszJ?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your stylesheet content with this:

```
.no-extras {
  border: 1 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  background-color: white !important;
  cursor: default !important;
}
```

You have given border as 0 which is wrong.
Do not modify your bootstrap.css file as it will alter all disabled fields.
Also, adding !important gives precedence to your styling over default styling provided by bootstrap.

Comment: Not that I have a reference at hand, but I am sure I have read several places that to use "!important" is something that you should avoid doing (a "quick and dirty" approach, but I am not sure when it would be a good approach to use !important)... So if there is a way without using !important?

Comment: Here is one reference that recommend to avoid using !important unless you really, really have to: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/ I have really little knowledge of css, but my gut feeling is that this perhaps is not the case where I would really need to use !important. But on the other hand, I might be wrong! Am I?

Comment: Ok. I will accept this answer, since it solves the question and this is better than altering the changing the bootstrap.css-file. And I will then make another question on how to get rid of !important. Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: Look here to see how to remove the not-recommended use of !important: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560966/want-to-override-bootstrap-but-how-to-avoid-the-use-of-important

Answer (score 1):

Fast approach: You could use the !important tag in your style to override bootstraps styling.

Cleaner approach: Eliminate the styling from the Bootstrap stylesheet (right click in Chrome/Firefox and inspect your input field to find the code).

What I found on line 2387 in your bootstrap.css:

```
.form-control[disabled], .form-control[readonly], fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
cursor: not-allowed;
background-color: #eee;
opacity: 1;
```

Comment: An approach without !important, but unfortunately, I am pretty sure that changing the bootstrap.css itself is not a recommended thing to do! In addition, it then fails the second half of my question (I need this only for one form, not as a general change for all forms)...