# Want to override Bootstrap, but how to avoid the use of !important?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and want to override some css: I am removing the background, border and the not-allowed-pointer in form fields when in disabled state.

This is how my css looks:

```
.no-extras {
  border: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  background-color: white !important;
  cursor: default !important;
}
```

But I know it is a bad thing to use !important. But how should I change the code to avoid using !important? I have tried to make it more specific, with "input.no-extras" and similar, but have not had any luck so far...

See example code here http://plnkr.co/edit/1AuszJ?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override CSS simply by being more specific with your selectors. Anything that selects the same tag in a more specific way is enough to override an existing definition. So, for example, putting a `form` reference before the target class is enough:

```
form .form-control[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/X86MFLOtso4uWrKMwbEW?p=preview)

Comment: [here is a good article on css specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: I like this :) But why does it not work to do "form .no-extras"? Is this not "putting a form reference before the target class"?

Comment: Eric - I checked my Plunker link and it looks fine here (see extra style definition in the head). Re why `form .no-extras` doesn't work: it's all down to css specificity rules as Bartdude mentioned... `.form-control[disabled]` is both a class and an an attribute selector, so counts for two. See: http://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: Oh, sorry @GrantGibson, I did not notice that you had css in the header (and not in the style.css-file). Thanks!

Comment: I will accept this answer because this is a little more general that the ".form-group .no-extras"-answer (I do not have to use a parent class). Anyway, thanks you all for your help :)

Comment: Oh, one more reason for accepting this specific answer is that it is an solution where I do not need to add my own class name (but uses the existing form-control).

Answer (score 5):

Your adding `.no-extras` only in `.form-group` so you can use:

```
.form-group .no-extras {
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: default;
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bWg53djUY7sW2brwagoh?p=preview)

Or you can use any other parent class.

Comment: And the ironic thing is that I in the end used this answer (even though the accepted one is a tiny bit better answer for my question). This is because I had some other needs that was not included in the question, so this actually fitted me perfectly. Thanks, @Vucko :)